# Firestore query timestamp gives 'Your function timed out'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firestore collection of order requests where I query booking time and status, below is the screenshot of the database

[image]

now my query based on multiple clauses all of them work fine but whenever I try to query timestamp it failed and I get this error:- `Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout`. I tried to google how to add query for timestamp all of them suggest the same thing which I have been using so far. Below is my code
This is `init.ts` file:-

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
admin.initializeApp();
export const db = admin.firestore();
export const timestamps = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

functions.logger.debug(`timestamps of server .== ${timestamps.seconds}`);
export const auth = admin.auth();
```

This is how I'm fetching my orders so it basically based on status and timestamp

`get-order.ts`

```
import {db, timestamps} from "../init";
const express = require('express');
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import 'firebase/firestore'

import {getUserCredentialsMiddleware} from "../auth.middleware";

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
export const getOrderDetails = express();
const date = timestamps.seconds;

getOrderDetails.use(bodyParser.json());
getOrderDetails.use(cors({origin:true}));
getOrderDetails.use(getUserCredentialsMiddleware);

getOrderDetails.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    
    try {
        functions.logger.debug(`Calling getOrderDetails try.== ${req.body}`);
        db.collection('orderRequest')
        .where('status', '==', 'Pending')
        .where('meta.booking_time', '<', date)
        .get().then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
     
            return res.json(documentSnapshot)
        });
     })
   }
   catch(err) {
       functions.logger.error(`Could not getOrderDetails.`, err);
       res.status(500).json({message: "Could not getOrderDetails."});
   }
 });
```

My `index.ts` file

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { getOrderDetails } from "./order-request/get-orders";

export const getRecentOrders = 
    functions.https.onRequest(getOrderDetails);
```

So now whenever I remove the timestamp query it works fine and got a response instantly but when I add it back it gives me timeout error, so my question is does the query with timestamp is time-consuming? What if my order list is big? does querying timestamp is a feasible option? and what I was doing wrong, why I didn't get the order details because everywhere it explains the same.

Comment: You are importing the firebase-functions module, but you never build and export an HTTPS function as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  That's confusing to me.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have updated my question, I exported in other file sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

Firstly, your function doesn't send anything back to the client if the query results are empty.  If you don't send a response to the client, the function will time out.  You will have to explicitly decide and code what you want to send in the event that there are no matching documents.

Secondly, you are calling `res.json()` more than once (inside a loop) in the case where you do have multiple documents.  You should only call `res.json()` once with the complete object to send back to the client.

Comment: I added the catch statement so now the timeout error stopped and also removed the `res.json()` but why query is not working? Do I have to save timestamp in seconds for this??

Comment: That sounds like a different question that you should post separately along with specific debugging details.